# SELECT from external data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's consider a made up example

```
SELECT id, name, score.score FROM
        someTable,
        (select someTableId, count(*) as score FROM SecondTable GROUP BY someTableId) as score 
    WHERE score.someTableId == id
    ORDER BY score.score DESC
```

Let's now assume that I have a backend computing my scoring, and that I would like to remove the subquery and insert my own data instead. I would like to know how to do this.

**I would like to do something like** (this is the question, because what's below doesn't work):

```
SELECT id, name, score.score FROM
        someTable,
        ((12,324), (1, 342)) as score(id, score)
    WHERE score.someTableId == id
    ORDER BY score.score DESC
```

Here is an example of external data substitution to a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT user_id FROM posts WHERE thread_id = 12 GROUP BY user_id);
```

Without a subquery and with external data:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (1,2,3);
```

Comment: did you forget the question?

Comment: Fair comment, I have added in bold where I would like the community attention and help ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly :

```
SELECT id, name, score.score FROM
        someTable,
        (SELECT 12 as someTableId,324 as score UNION ALL SELECT 1, 342 <UNION ALL....>) as score(id, score)
WHERE score.someTableId == id
ORDER BY score.score DESC
```

Thats the only way you can do it, it doesn't actually replace the the subquery, but it replace the select from the table and can improve performance if thats what you are looking for.

In MySQL you don't need to specify a `from` clause like a dummy table when you are just looking to fetch dummy data.

Comment: I have accepted the first answer as it was the first and complete enough for me to get it. Though, many thanks for be both of you ! I have learned something new, thank both of you guys!

Comment: Actually, I was the first answer by 2 minutes and my answer was complete, but accept what ever you like.. @aster

Comment: You are right, I have adjusted it. I have upvoted both (I think you actually both replied with the same speed and quality ... but I have to accept one right.

Answer (score 2):

Other DBMS require a dummy table name (typically `DUAL`) but in MySQL it's rather straightforward:

```
SELECT 12 AS id, 324 AS score
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 65
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 598
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 244
```

You can use this as any other result-set.

Comment: As usual, it depends on data size and what you try to do with it. If you need to deal with very large "virtual" data sets you could use a temporary table where you can at least create indexes (if I'm not confused with some other DBMS).